# Concat conditions to existing query in ScalikeJDBC

Tags: scala, scalikejdbc

I am using ScalikeJDBC in my project and I have an SQL query like this

```
    val str = "select name, age from employee"
    val selectQueryString = sqls"$str"
    val like = "%" + term + "%"

    val emp: List[Employee] = db.localTx { implicit session =>
           sql"#$selectQueryString where name like ${like} order by age"
             .map(rs => Employee(rs.string("name"), rs.int("age")))
             .list()
             .apply()
    }
```

But when I run the program I get Error like this.

> Failed preparing the statement (Reason: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0

My requirement is, I already have a safe SQL query which is a string and I want to add conditions to that, so that the query is safe from SQL injection.